# VBA - Añadir negrillas, formato en VBA exportando de Excel a Word

Tags: excel, vba, formato

Tengo este código que toma los valores de una hoja de Excel y genera un documento de Word. Quisiera saber cómo puedo ponerle negrillas en ciertas partes de la cadena, las que aquí están marcadas con **:

```
Sub exportar()
Dim objWord As Word.Application
Dim cadena As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim archivosalida As String

Dim ColA As String
Dim ColB As String

archivosalida = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & ".docx"

i = 1

Range("A1").Select
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ColA = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value
    ColB = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value

    cadena = cadena & "**Lorem ipsum** dolor sit amet " & **ColA** & ", " & ColB & vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    i = i + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Loop

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

objWord.Documents.Add
objWord.ActiveDocument.Content.FormattedText.Text = cadena
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs archivosalida
objWord.Quit True
Set objWord = Nothing
End Sub
```

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. ¿Que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Hola, aparte de intentar usar la propiedad Font.Bold = True , que no sirve, he hecho lo mismo pero generando un documento html y usando las etiquetas html para darle formato. Eso es fácil pero requiere pasar después el html a word. Una alternativa sería eso, generar el html y luego convertirlo automáticamente a un documento de word, y este último paso, el de conversión, es el que me falta y todavía no sé muy bien como hacer.

Comment: Tendrás que ponerlas en negrita en Word. VBA para Word tiene un objeto dentro de su jerarquía que se llama Selection, y es el texto seleccionado, y se puede poner en negrita con `Selection.Font.Bold` Y tiene comandos como `MoveUp, MoveDown` y más. Tendrás que diseñar una macro que te permita localizar las palabras a poner en negrita, y hacerlo, pero usando jerarquía de VBA para Word.